# Skipping first 3 posts in wp query

Tags: posts, wp-query, pages, pagination, exclude

Here's the query i have used.

```
 <?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 $wp_query = new WP_Query('order=asc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&posts_per_page=6&paged=' . $paged); ?>
```

Is there any way to skip the first 3 posts only in the first page (?paged=1) and not the other pages (?paged=2....).

Answer (score 6):

For skipping the post just use offset parameter in wp_query.

To display latest three post :

```
<?php
$latestpost = new WP_Query('order=asc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&posts_per_page=3');

//Here add loop to display posts like

while($latestpost->have_posts()) : $latestpost->the_post();

the_title();

the_content();

endwhile; wp_reset_query();

//After that skip three posts using offset

 $latestpost = new WP_Query('order=asc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&posts_per_page=6&offset=3&paged=' . $paged); 

the_title();

the_content();

endwhile; wp_reset_query();

?>
```

That's it

Comment: but that messes up the pagination i.e pagination doesnt work..anyways thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/10-useful-wordpress-loop-hacks/#2-use-more-than-one-loop-on-a-page-without-printing-duplicate-posts

Well i just followed this method and made some changes to it...

```
// in functions.php
$mega = new WP_Query('order=asc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&posts_per_page=3');
//set the posts per page to 3 so the id's of the first 3 posts will be shown 
$ids = array();
while ($mega->have_posts()) : $mega->the_post();
$ids[] = get_the_ID();

endwhile;
```

After that to the main loop for skipping first three posts loop which i changed a bit.

```
   $args= array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'posts_per_page' => 6,
'paged' => $paged,
'order'=> 'asc',
'orderby'=> 'meta_value',
'meta_key'=>'date',
'post__not_in' => $ids

 );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

And it works like i wanted..

Answer (score 0):

By using the offset parameter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query('order=asc&orderby=meta_value&meta_key=date&posts_per_page=6&offset=3&paged=' . $paged); ?>
```

Comment: it messes up the pagination.. ?paged=2 shows the same posts

Comment: @MeghGandhi do you understand that pagination not working has nothing to do with setting `offset` parameter. Your query is already messed up pagination.

Comment: actually wordpress generates its own offset which makes the pagination work and when we manually set the parameters it breaks the pagination.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Comment: I would have another look at the pagination.. it can be tricky to implement properly sometimes. Please try the query without the `posts_per_page` and `paged` properties and see if it paginates correctly based on the WordPress default setting ( Settings > Reading ).

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/10-useful-wordpress-loop-hacks/#2-use-more-than-one-loop-on-a-page-without-printing-duplicate-posts well i used this method and added the code to the functions and its working yay!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `offset` attribute have you thought about creating a var with a value of 1 is incremented in the loop. If the loop if less than 4 do nothing, else

```
<?php
    $p=1;
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if($p > 3) {
?>
// DO STUFF
```

This doesn't address the issue, but you may be able to set a condition that if this is the first page then skip the first 3?